# How to delete unused blobs in docker registry?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have a docker registry which I use for development.
Every image I push is retagged with the tag `:latest`.
So there are a lot of unreferenced images/blobs.
I try to clean the image by running the GC but this does not seem to help:

```
docker exec -it id bin/registry garbage-collect  /etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

The env var `REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED` is on True
This is probably because there are still `sha256` in my revision.

I'm able to delete an image using curl and the API. Than I use the tag and to delete the right `sha256` in revision. And then I'm albe to delete unused blobs using the GC script.

But when I repush on the same tag it's not able to delete the unused revisions and unused blobs.

Comment: Same workflow for me. Any update @DenCowboy ?

Comment: Not really. I've a "quick fix" in my script. After a run of the GC I'm performing: `docker restart registry-container-id`. This seems to help to repush later.